# Chrome failed to start: exited normally. error thrown when running selenium web driver tests in chrome on a computer that is on a domain

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(chrome not reachable)

1. Executing selenium web driver tests against chrome browser
2. Computer is on a AD domain when running on private account issue is not present
3. no headles i need the actual browser. in headless is working fine
4. selenium webdriver version 4.18.1 chrome version 122.0.6261.95 OS Windows 11

chrome options:

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-application-cache");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-automation");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
```

this issue was noticed with Chrome version 113 and I am anable to find solution since.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the following registry and solved the issue: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\